# (Scheme) Changing value in an array of booleans using a list

Tags: arrays, boolean, scheme, racket, bitvector

I need to make an array of booleans (0 or 1) with size 800000. I also need to be able to check/change the value at an index whenever I can. **I cannot use vectors or the command `set!`.**

I was looking at the documentation and found `build-list` [ [1](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._build-list%29%29) ]. So I made an array of zeros like this:

`(define arrBool (build-list 800000 (lambda (x) (* x 0))))`

I know I can access an index with `list-ref` [ [2](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._list-ref%29%29) ]. However, I cannot find anything in the documentation on how to change a value at that index. For example, if I want to change the `0` at index 27392 to a `1`, how would I go about doing this without making a whole new list?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: In Racket lists are immutable so you can't do that. Are you supposed to use Racket, a teaching language, or traditional Scheme?

Comment: We are supposed to use Racket. Is there any other way I can do this then? I used vectors at first but my professor didn't accept it since he wants us to use regular lists, so I'm at a loss on how to proceed.

Comment: You could use boxes; I doubt that this is your professor's intention but I'll post an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [boxes](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/boxes.html?q=box) although it's awkward:

```scm
> (define arrBool (build-list 20 (lambda (x) (box 0))))
> arrBool
'(#&0 #&0 #&0 #&0 #&0 #&0 #&0 #&0 #&0 #&0 #&0 #&0 #&0 #&0 #&0 #&0 #&0 #&0 #&0 #&0)
> (set-box! (list-ref arrBool 2) 1)
> (set-box! (list-ref arrBool 9) 1)
> arrBool
'(#&0 #&0 #&1 #&0 #&0 #&0 #&0 #&0 #&0 #&1 #&0 #&0 #&0 #&0 #&0 #&0 #&0 #&0 #&0 #&0)
> (unbox (list-ref arrBool 0))
0
> (unbox (list-ref arrBool 2))
1
```

**EDIT**

To set some indices to 1 when building the list, do

```scm
(define (make-list size indices-to-set)
  (build-list size (lambda (i) (if (member i indices-to-set) 1 0))))
```

then

```scm
> (make-list 20 '(2 9))
'(0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately he doesn't want us using boxes either (just asked). Although, I did learn something new; so that's awesome! Can I do this another way? When building the list, can I set certain indexes to 1?

Comment: If you need to use immutable lists then you have to create a new list every time you want to update an element.

Comment: Was afraid of that; especially considering the size of the list. Thank you though!

Comment: You can set values to 1 when building a list; will post an example.

Comment: You're welcome. One could program this in a more efficient way given the size of "array" you're supposed to handle. In real life you'd use vectors though.

Comment: Sorry, just one more question. How would I reference that list in other areas my program? Tried a variety of ways, but I can't just call it like I did with `arrBool`.

Comment: You'd need to post your code so that somebody can have a look at it. Maybe ask a new question?